# ASP.NET Webform Ajax doesn't seem to work with other PC

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webforms, popup

I have a website deployed in a remote PC and I have uploaded it in the Server Manager of that PC. I used AJAX ModalPopupExtender with my code to achieve the pop-up form.

My problem is when I view my website in remote PCs, the AJAX is working fine. This is how it looks like when AJAX is working, it has Black transparent background.

**https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLY6f.jpg**

Then here's how it looks like when I run it to my local pc and also to other PC of my workmates.

**https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3nWa.jpg**

You can also notice that the close "X" icon is not in the right side. Its just on top of the panel-header.

I am a newbie in Web development, hopefully someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like resources were not loaded properly.Take a look in firebug or dev tool whether all requests completed. Perhaps, some css reference is wrong.

Comment: It's now fixed. Just a couple of hours then it loaded correctly now. Maybe its just a cache issue only with my browser

Answer (score 0):

It's now fixed. Just a couple of hours then it loaded correctly now. Maybe its just a cache issue only with my browser